# Joe Eames tutorial Multivision -- Jade convert

Tags: html, pug, mean-stack

I am following Joe Eames tutorial - Buiding Angular JS and Node.js Apps withe MEAN stack-- and got stuck on the part of 'Persistinh Login between page refreshed'

This project done with .Jade but I went with just html. So, there is jade file showing

```
if !!boostrappedUser
script.
window.bootstrappedUserObject = !{JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser)}
```

I converted

```
<script>

if(!!boostrappedUser){window.bootstrappedUserObject = !{JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser)}
```

}

unfortunately, it did not go through.

what is the exact conversion that jade code to html?

Comment: You cannot translate it to HTML like that. `!{JSON.stringify(bootstrappedUser)}` is a Jade specific term.

Comment: What's gonna be for HTML?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477351/bootstrappeduser-jade-or-ejs-to-html

Comment: Just wonder if you have success converting this project to html?

Answer (score 0):

this one doesn't require any conversion, the result will be generated one the run time something like  this

```
    <script>
    window.bootstrappedUserObject = {
"_id":"53f00772eea207ab2f164332",
"firstName":"asdf",
"lastName":"asdf",
"userName":"jl",
"salt":"1y5kZRC+0IuWLFKvmiZ3miO1X4WOyloOYDhgQmhaEEZ4Ioji0AYCDMTZmvYd7yO/8QVRk4gsq7PrJ7XjbZJyJRCm1T6ejCDEin2R+6eN+QOu6pLdC/mOWvbxsAcaxI5Ko6t511OYDyw6I1OxoNMCadme2rMYmsczJOvSVPG6Okw=",
"hashed_password":"e7dbd23b3d71c4348c6708e7f07e446332275d80","__v":0,
"roles":[]}
</script>
```

just to ensure that the system would get the same user information if you refreshed the brower